# Name of simplest poker variant where no actions are involved?

Tags: poker-history

I'm not a poker player, but I'm just looking for the name of the simplest poker variant, where each player is simply dealt five cards face up, whoever has the better hand wins, and that's the end of the game. Purely luck-based and no actions possible for either player.

I tried reading the Wikipedia page but it doesn't seem to be there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_variants

Comment: It sounds similar to 5-card stud. Have you looked at https://www.pagat.com/poker/variants/ ?

Comment: @HerbWolfe 5 card stud has betting rounds and hidden information, so doesn't really fit the description of what the OP is looking for.

Comment: I have heard everyone forced to go all "suicide".  It would be like suicide with no chips.

Comment: There is no variant of poker that does not involve betting. What makes any game a poker game is the dynamic of betting, one does not need cards to play poker.

Answer (score 1):

5 Card Showdown. Each player antes a predetermined amount to be played for, then all cards are dealt face up best hand wins

Answer (score 0):

I used to play a game called **Seven Card Sweat**.

The game was very simple and it was purely for fun / to gamble. It is also very similar to what you are describing.

Each player is dealt seven cards face-down. The first player reveals their first card and stops. The second player reveals cards until they have a five-or-less card hand that beats the other players. This continues until all players have revealed all of their cards, and the player with the best five card hand at the end wins all of the money.

The turn taking is purely for entertainment e.g. the *sweat* aspect. There is no strategy.

---

For example two players:

*Each get dealt seven cards face-down.*

Player A: K♠ --- `King High`

Player B: 2⋄ 3♥ A♠ --- `Ace High`

Player A: K♠ 8⋄ 4♥ 9♣ 4⋄ --- `Pair of Fours`

Player B: 2⋄ 3♥ A♠ A⋄ --- `Pair of Aces`

Player A: K♠ 8⋄ 4♥ 9♣ 4⋄ K♣ --- `Two Pair; Kings and Fours`

Player B: 2⋄ 3♥ A♠ A⋄ 4♣ 7♠ 5♠ --- `Straight; Ace through Five`

Player A: K♠ 8⋄ 4♥ 9♣ 4⋄ K♣ K♥ --- `Full House; Kings full of Fours`

Player B: *"Wow that's so sick. Take your money!"*

It can be played with as many players as the deck allows, which is seven.

Answer (score 0):

5 card stud is the game you are looking for.
Face up, or down, or any combination thereof, usually dealer makes the choice to structure betting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with a term for a game that deals five cards face up and has no actions possible for either player.

In five card stud, players decide whether to bet or fold, and one card is face down.

Some online sites have "Kamikaze" tournaments, where all players are forced all-in pre-flop in Texas Hold'em.
No decisions are made by the players.
However, it is not five cards face up.

[Example](https://gamesandcasino.com/poker-promos/kamikaze-poker-tournaments/490.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like 5 card draw, similar to what is played on video poker machines.

Each player is dealt 5 cards face down and gets a chance to replace any cards they would like (from 0 to all 5) between 2 rounds of betting before showdown.

unlike what you describe, this form of poker uses betting and each player gets a chance to replace some of his/her cards.